# how to set the equal length of question marks in latex que paper

Tags: questionnaire

I want to put the marking of each question in right side of paper equally. How to set the equal length of question marks in latex que paper ?

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,floatfix,amsmath,preprint,showpacs,12pt]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\linespread{1}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\topmargin=0.5cm \oddsidemargin=-0.9cm
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\begin{document}
\baselineskip=1.0\baselineskip

All questions are compulsory. \\
\begin{enumerate}
\item[Q. 1 (a)] My Question prove that ...? [Mark here]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are yo using any existing, special, document class to create your *que*stionnaire paper? how about providing the community with a template document that shows your setup? This template should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Include a couple of questions using dummy text (possible from [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum)).

Comment: Yes, the document class is {revtex4}

Comment: ...then show us via a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: The easiest way to achieve what you're looking for might be via `\newcommand{\points}[1]{\hfill\makebox[0pt][l]{[#1]}`. This will print the points/marks in the right column for 99.9% of its uses. 0.01% may overflow to the next line where it's used, but a question rewording quickly takes care of that.

Comment: how to apply it after question for putting marks ?

Comment: I could show you, if you show some example code...

Comment: How I paste it?

Comment: \documentclass[aps,pra,floatfix,amsmath,preprint,showpacs,12pt]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\linespread{1}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\topmargin=0.5cm
\oddsidemargin=-0.9cm
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05} 


\begin{document}
\baselineskip=1.0\baselineskip

All questions are compulsory. \\

\begin{enumerate}
\item[Q. 1 (a)] My Question prove that ...?          [Mark here]



\end{enumerate}


\end{document}

Comment: I've edited your question to include the code you provided. If you need to make further changes, click the Edit button below your question.

Comment: and you can delete your last comment

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following might be a good start:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,enumitem}
\geometry{margin=1cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\marksA}[1]{\hfill\makebox[0pt][l]{~[#1]}}
\newcommand{\marksB}[1]{\hfill\makebox[0pt][r]{[#1]}}

\newcounter{newquestion}
\setlist[enumerate]{before={\stepcounter{newquestion}},label={Q.\ \thenewquestion (\alph*)},align=left}

\begin{document}
All questions are compulsory.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item My question prove that ...? [Mark here]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item My question prove that ...? \marksA{10}
  \item My question prove that ...? \marksA{5}
  \item My question prove that ...? \marksA{1}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item My question prove that ...? \marksB{10}
  \item My question prove that ...? \marksB{5}
  \item My question prove that ...? \marksB{1}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

`\marksA` or `\marksB` puts the marks either flush left/right around the margin. `\marksA` would work best since it allows your questions to sit within the entire `\textwidth` block, if need be.

You'll note that I've used `article` with layout set via [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) and [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for list processing.

Comment: In case of any mathematical equation it appears in next line, and taking a big space. So how we can put it in same line where our equation is.

Comment: @DeepeshPatel: Try setting the marks on the last line of text before the equation. If this is not satisfactory, then you could try ``\[ \makebox[\textwidth]{\displaystyle ...}\marksA{..} \]``.